# Banning certain programs from using wake from sleep

Tags: windows-7, wake-up

Is it possible to ban a particular program from waking up the computer from sleep on Windows 7.  The media center update is becoming really irritating turning my computer on all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look in

> Windows Media Center settings ->
>   General -> Automatic Download Options